# How Does AWS Kinesis confirm that an event has been received?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We are using AWS Kinesis in a stream processing project and I want to know how does it confirm or notice that a message has been received, and furthermore, if exists a way to configure it. I don´t find anything in their documentation.

As AWS Kinesis is based on a Kafka fork, It may be a way to configure this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinesis is serverless and exposed via HTTP, different from Kafka and [AWS MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/) that uses the Kafka protocol over TCP.

Records are sent via [PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) or [PutRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) API calls and received via [GetRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html) API call.

For **data producers** you check the response of the API call to confirm the record was added to the stream, sample response for PutRecords from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amzn-RequestId: <RequestId>
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
Content-Length: <PayloadSizeBytes>
Date: <Date> 
{
    "FailedRecordCount": 2,
    "Records": [
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49543463076548007577105092703039560359975228518395012686", 
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000"
        }, 
        {
            "ErrorCode": "ProvisionedThroughputExceededException",
            "ErrorMessage": "Rate exceeded for shard shardId-000000000001 in stream exampleStreamName under account 111111111111."
        },
        {
            "ErrorCode": "InternalFailure",
            "ErrorMessage": "Internal service failure."
        }
    ]
}
```

For **data consumers** you don't notify the stream that the messages were received, records are available to all consumers until they expire, it works on a pull model.

The consumer is responsible to [interact over the shards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html) and receive new messages.

If you want to build a custom consumer, AWS has a [client library (KCL)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/shared-throughput-kcl-consumers.html) that handles the stream processing for you.

Comment: Thanks you answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the [PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) API, you will either receive an error or a response with `ShardId` and `SequenceNumber` fields that tell you where the message was stored. The [PutRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) API is similar, except that the response will give you the status of every record that you wrote, and *some records from a batch may fail while others succeed.*

If this does not answer your question, please *completely* describe how you are writing to Kinesis, and what you expect to see as a notification.